# In "Reign of Fire", did dragons emerge between Dinosaurs and the movie time?

Tags: reign-of-fire

In "Reign of Fire", they mentioned that dragons burnt the dinosaurs out.

Is there any indication in canon that they have emerged between that event, and the contemporary events of the movie?

Comment: What would be canon?  I don't see where this movie is based on a book or comic book.

Comment: @unclebrad - the usual: film, script, any extra materials on DVD if exist, interviews with creators, novelization if exists (in this case I'm not aware of the last)

Comment: @unclebrad - in this case, as you can see from Richard's answer, the needed canon was just the film's script

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [script](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=reign-of-fire) is explicit that the dragons have risen since the end of the age of the dinosaurs, typically decimating the planet and bringing on an ice age each time they do. There have been two ice ages in the past 300M years, the last ending just 22,000 years ago which would suggest that they've risen at least twice since the dinosaurs became extinct.

> *"**Ancient man had made them into myths**, but nature had made something far more terrible.*
>
> *Too late, our scientists discovered their true identity...a species which had burned the dinosaurs to dust, **whose ash had brought on ice
>   ages**, who, in eons past, had scorched the world clean of life,
>   waiting for the Earth to replenish itself, to start their cycle
>   anew.*"*